# Namenode daemon not starting properly

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode

I have just started learning hadoop from the book *Hadoop: The definitive guide*.

I followed the tutorial for Hadoop installation in Pseudodistribution mode. I enabled the passwordless login to *ssh*. 
Formatted the *hdfs* filesystem before using it for the first time. It started successfully for the first time.
After that I copied a text file using `copyFromLocal` to HDFS and everything went fine. But if I restart the system and start the daemons again and look at the web UI , only YARN is started successfully.

When I issue the stop-dfs.sh commmand I get

```
Stopping namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: no namenode to stop
localhost: stopping datanode
Stopping secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: stopping secondarynamenode
```

If I format the hdfs file system **again** and then try starting the daemons then they all start successfully.

Here are my configuration files.Exactly as what is told in hadoop definitive guide book.

*hdfs-site.xml*

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>    
        <value>1</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

*core-site.xml*

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost/</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

*mapred-site.xml*

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

*yarn-site.xml*

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>localhost</value>    
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

This is the error in the namenode log file

```
WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory /tmp/hadoop/dfs/name does not exist
 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Encountered exception loading fsimage
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /tmp/hadoop/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:975)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:812)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:796)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1559)
```

This is from mapred log

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
    ... 33 more
```

I visited [apache hadoop : connection refused](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused) which says

- Check that there isn't an entry for your hostname mapped to 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1 in /etc/hosts (Ubuntu is notorious for this).

I found there is an entry in my /etc/hosts, but if I remove it my sudo breaks causing error `sudo: unable to resolve host` . What should I append in `/etc/hosts` if not remove my hostname mapped to 127.0.1.1

I cannot understand what is the root cause of this problem.

Comment: Have you mentioned the address of name node in core-site.xml as localhost

Comment: @siddharthajain Yes, configuration file is not the problem because daemon started the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it says in your Namenode log file that default storage of your namenode directory is `/tmp/hadoop`. The `/tmp` directory is formatted in linux on reboot by some systems. So it must be the problem.

You need to change your default namenode and datanode directory by changing your `hdfs-site.xml` configuration file.

Add this in your `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:///home/"your-user-name"/hadoop</value> 
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:///home/"your-user-name"/datanode</value>   
    </property>
```

After this format your namenode by `hdfs namenode -format` command.

I think this will end your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If configuration file is not a problem, please try following:

1.first delete all contents from temporary folder:

```
 rm -Rf <tmp dir> (my was /usr/local/hadoop/tmp)
```

2.format the namenode:

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

3.start all processes again:

```
bin/start-all.sh
```

Comment: I wrote in my question that if I format namenode then the daemons starts successfully but if I do something in fs like `copyFromLocal` then the problem arrives again. Only YARN runs on localhost but not hdfs and mapreduce.

Comment: Also `start-all.sh` is deprecated and you should start daemons respectively.